# Most efficient way to render separated, random triangles?

Tags: javascript, webgl

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75048835/triangles2/index.html

Here what this script does every frame:

- Get the slider value
- If the slider value is changed, create one Float32Array for vertices and one for colors with it's sizes adapted
- Run a loop, where each iteration adds a new triangle to the arrays,
  with random X, Y, RGB and alpha values
- Use gl.drawArrays to draw the arrays

The problem is that I can't get a decent framerate when I go at 800+ triangles. Is there any way to make this faster?

[Source code here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75048835/triangles2/script2.js)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use glBufferSubData rather than glBufferData. glBufferData would require a new buffer to be allocated every time it is called. Should see a big performance gain.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the variables that you're using are located as local as possible, so they don't continue to be referenced and hence occupying memorie. Global variables are not cleaned up by the garbage collector during the life of your page.

This article could be helpful: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/